# how to add view template in asp.net core

Tags: templates, asp.net-core, scaffolding

i want to add some view template for asp.net core mvc 3.1.1, i copied Templates folder from this path:"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\2.1.7\Templates"
and added a new view with name "_Entiti.cshtml" to "ViewGenerator" folder, but when trying to add a view it not appears in dialog box of vs 2019 inside of templates drop down, originally i want to use controller with context to generate some views with custom controller, but couldn't change view name that been created like "Create,List,...".
can any body help me?

Comment: If you want to add new templates to `dotnet new` or Visual Studio, you will have to create those explicitly. You cannot modify an existing package, and any modifications within the `NuGetFallbackFolder` are not supported. See [“Custom templates for dotnet new”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates).

Comment: i don't want to create template for whole project, just for controllerwithcontext auto generated views or if it's not possible just for views, like older version of vs

Answer (score 0):

Try using the solution explorer. Right click on the Shared folder (under Views) and click "Add" --> "View". 
Then on top of the pages that you would like to be using that template write:

**substitute the word "View" with the name of your template:

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/View.cshtml"; }
```

Comment: as i said i can't see my template name among template drop down items of wizard